# How should I connect a new RF switch to replace two standard switches?

Tags: electrical, electrical-distribution, neutral

I have two light switches. Each runs three lights and has its own hot and neutral wires (so in total--2 hots and 2 neutrals).

I bought this remote switch which accept only one in and two out. The old one is a normal switch the new one is an RF switch. How should it be wired?

[image][image]

Comment: You want to replace the two switches with a single switch? Can you post a picture of the switch box, clearly showing the wires?

Comment: Please name the make and model of the remote switch. - One in and two out doesn't make sense; it should have something like one neutral, one hot (Probably marked "line"), and one switched (probably marked "load").

Comment: What don't you like about the old switches, and what are you trying to do with the new switch?

Comment: @mmathis. Thats exactly what i am planning to do

Comment: The model will help. With L1,L2,L3 it would look like a 3 phase switch so we need to look up the schematic. As a Guess I would think L is for the incoming hot then there are 3 switches or the ability to switch 3 diferent loads.

Comment: @Ed Beal it is 3 switches however i will only be using 2. But cannt do it as i have two neutral and two hot lines from the old setup

Comment: You can only use 1 of the hot lines to the switch (hopefully they are pigtailed in the back of the box).  It looks like the blue wire on the original switch powers both switches if this is the case put the blue on L then the feed for 1 set of lights on L1, the other on L2  make sure the neutrals from the panel and going to the 2 sets of lights are combined, Last connect your grounds, there should be one on the switch but it may be on the side out of view.

Comment: Do you mean i can combine the 2 neutrals?   Btw. I have two hot lines not one and two neutrals not one in the old setup

Comment: @MohammedAlamoudi By two hot lines, do you mean 2 blue (?) wires, or 2 wires that are live all the time, even when the switch is off?

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the box?

Comment: @mmathis. The lights are divided into two separate circuits each switch has its own hot and neutral wire. The old switch setup connects one hot with neutral in each switch. I tries to do the following for the new setup.  In L i plugged one hot line and in L1 i plugged one neutral and in L3 i plugged the other neutral.     Three out of the six lights worked. I tried to plug in the other hot line in L the result was the other three lights are working!

Comment: @mmathis. The lights are divided into two separate circuits each switch has its own hot and neutral wire. The old switch setup connects one hot with neutral in each switch. I tried to do the following for the new setup.  In L i plugged one hot line and in L1 i plugged one neutral and in L3 i plugged the other neutral.     Three out of the six lights worked. I tried to plug in the other hot line in L the result was the other three lights are working!     What do you think about plugging neutral in L and each hot line in L1 and L3.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel. It is up there

Comment: @MohammedAlamoudi -- looking into the back of the *box* -- right now, I see a hot going to both switches and then off to somewhere else, and 2 switched hots, but *no* neutrals! Also, where on the planet *are* you?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel. Hehehe... This is Saudi with a stupid person did that wiring. When i do the tester test both yellow wires full of electricity heheh..   The other blue and green are normal to hold

Comment: The L1 - L3 labeling also looks like a [4-way lightswitch](http://users.wfu.edu/matthews/misc/switches/4WayAnimation.html)